# laravel php 5.4 running on apache server

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-403

i get a 403 when i browse to the root directory of my laravel project. When i go to root/public i do get a you have arrived message from the framework. But this isnt what is supposed to be right? How do i make my project so that when i go to the root i actually get into /public?

i have tried the following:

This is how my htaccess file looks like in in the root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `DocumentRoot` properly in your Apache configuration. This is separate from the `.htaccess` and it should point at the `public` directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't configure apache directories, for production environment, put 2 `.htaccess` files.

The 1. is in the *root* folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The 2. is in the */public* folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your first file is THE ONLY THING that worked for me in Laravel 5.1. I didn't need to change the second file. Thanks, buddy!